# How to get information to the BackgroundAgend from the App in WP7/C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i have a problem.
i'm using the background agend to update my live tile.

now i want to extend this feature and get a integer from the main app. this integer change often and so i would like to get access to the app from the background agend.

the problem is, that i have a reference from the app to the background abend, so i can not add a reference in the background agend to the app.

how can i find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main app could save this Integer to Isolated Storage. Background agent can access it when needed.

Comment: the problem is, that the number will change when the methods from the main app are called. when i store it in the storage it will be not possible to update them activly.

Comment: put update code in different library and reference it both from main app and background agent

Comment: Still this is just saving value to a file and reading it. Remember that it might be that they never are running at the same time - thus you have to make this communication through file system.